# Use javascript while loop to make variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, loops, while-loop

There are topics about this, but not realy pointed at my problem.

I'm using iScroll, a jquery plugin. For every scrollbox on my page I need to assign a unique variable. In this case it's gonna be myScroll1, myScroll2 etc.

To make it easily editable, I want the variables to be automatically generated giving the number of div's in wich the scrollbars are in. So, let's say I have 2 divs with these scrollbars. I use the .size() method to count the divs. Then I want a while loop to make the variables. I now have something like this:

```
var i = 0;
var item_number = $(".portfolio_item").size();

var myScroll = [];
while( i < item_number ) {
    myScroll[i];
    i++;
}
```

Sooo, I don't want anything generated in the HTML, just the variables. They have to become myScroll1, myScroll2, myScroll3. Depending on the amount of .portfolio_item divs.

I have tried this with php, that's a bit easier for me. But!! I can't use javascript variables in php. So I can't count the amount of .portfolio_item divs :(
Thank you! :)

Comment: Do you want to make global variables (if so, reconsider; that's bad practice)? Why a separate one for each item? An array would be much better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad practice, but you can do this

```
var i = 0;
var item_number = $(".portfolio_item").size();

while( i < item_number ) {
    window["myScroll" + i] = "foo" + i;
    i++;
}

alert(myScroll0);
```

better practice is to use a namespace and add to it.

```
var i = 0;
var item_number = $(".portfolio_item").size();

var foo = {};
while( i < item_number ) {
    foo["myScroll" + i] = "foo" + i;
    i++;
}

alert(foo.myScroll0);
```